# Send keys for 2 fields using tab option in one command line

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying to automate a web page that requires to enter credentials to navigate to the page, so when enter the URL, a windows security window appear to enter user name and password then click on ok. 
I've tried the following code to enter the credentials, but is fills the value "username\tPassword" in the user name only without tab to the next field to enter the password (I'm using \t to switch to the password field)
how can I solve this problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users\\demah\\Desktop\\Selenium\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");

        WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get("URL");
        driver.findElement(By.id("overridelink")).click();

        Alert obj = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
        obj.sendKeys("username\tPassword");
        obj.accept();
```

Comment: driver.get("http:// username:password@URL");

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:** Handling Authentication/Login Popup Window using Selenium WebDriver
By passing user credentials in URL. Its simple, append your username and password with the URL.

> e.g., http://Username:Password@SiteURL

```
String URL = "http://" + username + ":" + myPassword + "@" + URL;
driver.get(URL);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

**Approach 2** : By using AutoIt, we could handle authentication pop up.
Refer the [link](https://www.softwaretestingmaterial.com/handle-authentication-popup-window/) for more details

Comment: driver.get("http:// username:password@url");
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();

Comment: but still give an error "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present with text: : "

Comment: ok first lets make it more clear, my webpage needs to enter the URL, then click on a link "Continue to this website (not recommended). " then the popup appear to enter the username and password,,, so first I've get the url then click on the link, then I need to enter the credentials to continue